# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el valor de miles en un textbox?

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo una tabla en base de datos `Decimal(18,2)` y un `textbox` que me ingresa solo números, pero si intento guardar un número con miles por ejemplo: 1,234.89, me da error de que **el formato no coincide con el método de entrada**, utilizo `procedimiento almacenados`. Lo que quiero saber es como guardar ese dato con miles, o dejar los miles 1,234.89 para solo la vista del usuario y que en mi tabla se guarde 1234.89 como se está guardando actualmente. No se cual seria la mejor manera. ¿Y cómo haría para que solo sea en la vista que se vea con miles y este no me afecte por si se llega a editar ese precio?

Answer (score 0):

Usa el siguiente metodo para obtener un decimal que incluye la coma como separador,
puedes eliminar    clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";  para no considerar al punto como separador haz pruebas y revisa si funciona para ti:

```
  public decimal TextoaDecimal(string s){
    var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
    // ejemplo string s = "1,14535765" o string s="1.141516";
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, clone);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Eso seria para la vista del usuario? o se guardaria asi en la base de datos? yo quiero que esten ambos la coma para los miles y el punto para los decimales 1,234.89 pero asi no se me guarda en la base de datos, por eso pregunto si es solo para el lado de la vista del cliente

Comment: Como  en tu pregunta pusiste C# tag pues supuse que antes de guardar puedes hacer la conveersion usando este metodo

Comment: ok, si uso C# pero si lo guardo con coma y punto me sale el error que comento ahi, por eso la pregunta que te dije era si eso es solo para la vista del usuario o me lo va a guardar asi, ya que no me permite ingresar el dato con ese formato

Answer (score 0):

Esto se realacion con la cultura que tiene la aplicacion, para que la reconozca deberias usar por ejemplo una cultura `en-US` algo como ser

```
decimal valor = Convert.ToDecimal("1,234.89", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Si aplicas la cultura correcta tomara el sistema de puntuacion que coincida con el que describes asi conviertes a un decimal valido que podrias usar en el parametro del procedure

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("nombreprocedure", "connection string");
//resto codigo
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Ok gracias Leandro dices que se puede escribir así y no me dara error al guardar? el numero "1,234.89", es una referencia de ejemplo, no digo que sea ese el que se va a guardar

Comment: estas usando un separador diferente,por eso aplique el 'punto y coma', pero si quires se puede usar otro como ser el '|'

Comment: gracias leandro, pero el problema es que en la base de datos no se me guarda, me sale el error que describo, igualmente muchas gracias por responder

Comment: usas parametros para asignar el valor o lo contatenas en el string ? porque sino usas parametro no te va a funcionar. Podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo que usas para generar el insert